# grab a div and attach a class jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

How can I grab this `#one-id` and attach a this `.myclass` to it using jQuery?

```
#one-id {
width: 120px;
height: 40px;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.myclass {border: 13px solid red}

<div id="one-id">CLASS</div>
```

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ynn5c/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses two fairly fundamental aspects of jQuery:

```
$("#one-id").addClass("myclass");
```

The [first part](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) `$("#one-id")` looks up matching element(s) using a CSS selector. In this case, because the element has an `id`, we're using an [`id` selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#id-selectors) and we'll get back at most one element (since only one element can have any given `id`), but jQuery is all about set theory, so it's still a "set" of elements (with one entry).

Then we call [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass) on that jQuery object, which adds the class to any elements in the set that don't already have it.

I recommend looking through some jQuery tutorials and spending an hour reading [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com).

Comment: +1 for swift and correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("#one-id").addClass("myclass");
```